# Exception Handling Adventure II

Tags: java, exception, foreach, try-catch

Lets say i have this -

```
for() { //this is a for-each loop

 try {

  //my logic

 } catch (Exception e) {

    System.out.println("Exception caught and handled");

    //Some more logic is written..Like calling a method from another class etc..

 } //end of try-catch block

}end of for-each loop
```

If an exception is handled, will that logic in the catch block execute? And after that, will i be able to go to the next iteration of the for-each loop?

Comment: Yes, of course. Yes, of course.

Comment: Consider creating a test project for checking such simple things. This will make you more confident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, If you will try by your own, you will get sonme more idea.

However Here are my thoughts--

- Yes. If any Exception been thrown inside try block, it will be `catch` in the catch block and the next iteration of for-each loop will be executed.
- BUT if, your business logic inside catch block throws any exception, your for loop will break. (And that's why, its not a good practice to put any business logic inside `catch` block) But, on a safer side, surround your business logic (which is inside the catch block) with another try-catch block i.e,

  ```
  for() { //this is a for-each loop
   try {
    //my logic
   } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception caught and handled");
          try{
          //Some more logic is written..Like calling a method from another class etc..
          } catch(Exception ex){
              System.out.println("Exception caught inside Catch Block and handled");
          }
   } //end of try-catch block
  }end of for-each loop
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The exception handling is not breaking the loop. Therefore it will iterate further.
The code in he catch-Block will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

In your try-catch block, the line that threw an exception will be the last one, that executes IN THE CURRENT ITERATION. In the next iteration you will start over again.

Of course, the catch block will execute in case you've got an exception.

Comment: So i must assume that if i put it outside the loop, the execution of that logic will terminate..Please correct me if I am wrong.